# aws.push to more than one environment

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two different environments running off of the same git repository.  it looks like in the AWS console tools for git and elastic beanstalk, I can only connect one environment at a time, is there anyway to have it push to both of my environments at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version allows you to map different branches to different repositories, see [Announcement: Deploy Git Branches to Multiple Elastic Beanstalk Environments](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1772):

> Starting today, you can use eb and Git to deploy branches to multiple
>   Elastic Beanstalk environments. You can also manage and configure
>   multiple Elastic Beanstalk environments using eb. For example, you can
>   configure eb and Git to deploy your development branch to your staging
>   environment and deploy your release branch to your production
>   environment. [...]